# Using same UITextFieldDelegate methods in custom UIView and in UIViewController simultaneously

Tags: ios, uitextfield, appdelegate, uitextfielddelegate

I have an `UIView` (named HCTextFieldView) with subviews: `UITextField` and `UILabel` above.

`UITextField's` delegate is equal to self. Delegate methods `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` perform textfield's background highlight effect.

Next I'am using this custom `UIView` (HCTextFieldView) in my `UIViewController`. To handle action of 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons in toolbar (attached above textfield's keyboard) I need the same textfield's delegate methods in `UIViewController`, **BUT** delegates became overridden.

```
**@interface HCBaseTextField : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>**
...
@end

**@implementation HCBaseTextField {}**

...

textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, titleLabel.bottom, self.width - 20, self.height - titleLabel.height)];
**textField.delegate = self**;

...

#pragma mark - UITextField delegate

//textFieldBG - UIImageView that act as background

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textFieldBg setImage:[[UIImage imageWithName:@"btn_vvod_medium_act"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10]];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textFieldBg setImage:[[UIImage imageWithName:@"btn_vvod_medium_norm"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10]];
    return YES;
}

...

@end


**ViewController : UIViewController**

...

HCTextFieldView *textFieldView = [[HCTExtFieldView alloc] init];
textFieldView.textField.delegate = self;

...

//I need to use this methods too but they override previous in UIView delegate
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.keyboardControls setActiveField:textField];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self.keyboardControls setActiveField:textView];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a `delegate` in `HCBaseTextField` like

in **HCBaseTextField.h** add a property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UITextFieldDelegate> textFieldDelagate;
```

and in **HCBaseTextField.m**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    ....
    if (self.textFieldDelagate && [self.textFieldDelagate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldBeginEditing:)]) {
        [self.textFieldDelagate textFieldShouldBeginEditing:textField];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    ....

    if (self.textFieldDelagate && [self.textFieldDelagate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)]) {
        [self.textFieldDelagate textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField];
    }
}

... //Other delegate methods if needed
```

and in **ViewController : UIViewController**

```
...

HCTextFieldView *textFieldView = [[HCTExtFieldView alloc] init];

textFieldView.textFieldDelagate = self;

...
```

and implement delegate methods.

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    ....

    //Do the stuff
}
```